# How do I speed up this function evaluation in matlab?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

Half the run time of my code right now is evaluating a big function over many, many points, it takes maybe about 20 seconds per evaluation

The function consists of a bunch of simple operations that look like

```
Ux = ((1./72).*(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2).^(-5./2).*((-5).*x.*(4.*x.^4+3.*y.^2.*( ...
  y.^2+z.^2)+x.^2.*(7.*y.^2+z.^2)).*gx^2+(-10).*y.*(3.*x.^4+5.* ...
  x.^2.*y.^2+2.*y.^2.*(y.^2+z.^2)).*gx.*gy+5.*x.*(x.^4+3.*y.^2.* ...
  z.^2+x.^2.*(y.^2+z.^2)).*gy^2));
```

is there any way to speed this up?  Additionally it spends like 10% of this function evaluation concatenating these large matrices as

```
U =[Ux;Uy;Uz];
```

Are there any tricks to speeding up these sorts of evaluations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you are doing some redundant computation, for example `y.^2+z.^2` is computed 4 times, with `y.^2` and `z.^2` are computed 9-10 times. You can define a set of variables `y2=y.^2`, `z2=y.^2`, `y2pz2=y2+z2;` and push some of the computation cost to memory -given that you have enough memory. That would save you a good amount of time.

MATLAB is a column-major language. Looking at your code, `Ux`, `Uy` and `Uz` seem to be row vectors and you are putting them on top of each other `U =[Ux;Uy;Uz];`. That will be slow. If possible, defining `U =[Ux',Uy',Uz'];` should reduce the time spent concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [arrayfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)? If the arrays are really large (how large are we speaking, by the way?), it might be possible that allocating all those temporaries has a cost that arrayfun would save.

Also, instead of concatenating, you could preallocate U and fill it one block at a time.